# Error in compiling using color package

Tags: color, compiling

I am preparing my dissertation. I am using pdfLaTeX. Document compiles fine, until I try to use `\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{color}` .  Everything shuts down.  I can access the `\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{color}` in other documents, but for the life of me can't figure out what is conflicting here.

My preamble is

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[subfigure, titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{doublespace}
\usepackage{citesort}   
\usepackage{colonequals}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathdots}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{color}
```

Comment: Is `\usepackage{xcolor}` enough for you?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using the code you have posted. Please edit your question so that it includes a complete example that does reproduce the problem. Note that there are lots of files called `thesis.sty`. Please provide a link to the one you are using.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, by the way.

Comment: "shuts down" isn't very descriptive, does tex stop or loop forever or ....

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance in terminology.  I am relatively new to LaTeX and the learning curve is steep.

Comment: The error message I receive is "Too many }'s.
\color@endbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup "

Comment: It does not matter what color package I use color or xcolor, the error seems to be directly tied to the very first figure box.

Comment: Here is the link to the particular style file https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qfucmqw3ld38pd/thesis.sty

Comment: see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/doublespace

Comment: The problem certainly comes from the body of your document, since I took your preamble and compiled with some stuff of mine without a problem. That said, your preamble has a few errors: 1) it's useless to load `graphics`since you load its extension `graphicx`. 2)`doublespace` is an old (LaTeX 2.09) package, that is superseded by `setspace`. 3) `subfigure`is obsolete and no more maintained; you should use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you using [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) in the figure? What happens when you compile using `latex`>`dvips`>`ps2pdf` rather than `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 4):

The thesis  file has

```
\input epsf.sty         % read in epsf macros for figures
\input doublespace.sty      % thesis is double-spaced
```

which are both spectacularly old packages from last century some time. I suspect that it is doublespace causing the problem (I don't have the file at all)

Comment out those lines (and don't load doublespace again in your preamble, as shown in the question)

To include figures use the standard `graphicx` package. If you must doublespace the document use the `setspace` package.